# Why does mongodb output differently using employees[0], employees[1], employees[2], versus a for loop using employees [i]?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop, mongodb-query

This is the query I am running:

```
var employees = db.worksOn.distinct("essn", { $or:[ {'hours': {$gt: 30}, 'pno': 1}, {'hours': {$lte: 20}, 'pno': 2}] }, {'essn': 1, '_id':0} );
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){
    db.employee.find( { 'ssn': employees[i] })
}
```

What is returned by the code:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc80d0531819bcbd5c3a842"), "fname" : "Joyce", "minit" : "A", "lname" : "English", "ssn" : 453453453, "bdate" : "1962-07-31", "address" : "5631 Rice, Houston, TX", "sex" : "F", "salary" : 25000, "superssn" : 333445555, "dno" : 5 }
```

Here is what the individual parts return:

```
var employees = db.worksOn.distinct("essn", { $or:[ {'hours': {$gt: 30}, 'pno': 1}, {'hours': {$lte: 20}, 'pno': 2}] }, {'essn': 1, '_id':0} )
employees
[ 123456789, 333445555, 453453453 ]
```

_

```
employees.length
3
```

_

```
db.employee.find({'ssn': employees[0]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc80d0531819bcbd5c3a845"), "fname" : "John", "minit" : "B", "lname" : "Smith", "ssn" : 123456789, "bdate" : "1955-01-09", "address" : "731 Fondren, Houston, TX", "sex" : "M", "salary" : 30000, "superssn" : 333445555, "dno" : 5 }
> db.employee.find({'ssn': employees[1]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc80d0531819bcbd5c3a846"), "fname" : "Franklin", "minit" : "T", "lname" : "Wong", "ssn" : 333445555, "bdate" : "1945-12-08", "address" : "638 Voss, Houston, TX", "sex" : "M", "salary" : 40000, "superssn" : 888665555, "dno" : 5 }
> db.employee.find({'ssn': employees[2]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc80d0531819bcbd5c3a842"), "fname" : "Joyce", "minit" : "A", "lname" : "English", "ssn" : 453453453, "bdate" : "1962-07-31", "address" : "5631 Rice, Houston, TX", "sex" : "F", "salary" : 25000, "superssn" : 333445555, "dno" : 5 }
```

Why does it output differently using employees[0], employees[1], employees[2], versus employees[i]?
The answer might be found in these two pieces of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){ employees[i] }
453453453

for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){ 
    print(employees[i]) 
}
123456789
333445555
453453453
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it output differently using employees[0], employees[1],
> employees[2], versus employees[i]?

In this `find` method (`db.employee.find( { 'ssn': employees[i] })`), the result is a ***cursor***. Note that a `find` always returns a cursor and `findOne` returns a document (or a `null`, if there is no matching document found). The cursor object can have zero or more documents, depending upon the query filter and the matched documents.

So, in your code if you want to print the result of the output of the query `db.employee.find( { 'ssn': employees[i] })`, you need to iterate thru the cursor. For example, you can do this in `mongo` shell:

```
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){
    var empCur = db.employee.find({ 'ssn': employees[i] });
    empCur.forEach(printjson);
}
```

This will print document(s) from the `empCur`. Note cursor has many other methods, and you can use any of them as per your use case.

References:

- [Iterate a find() returned
  Cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#iterate-the-returned-cursor)
- [Manually Iterate the
  Cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/index.html#manually-iterate-the-cursor)